# How can we set locally cached settings to "FALSE"?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

I want to set locally cached settings to false for particular nuget package.

[image]

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -NoCache in NuGet cli to download each time from the server.